# Fitting Gantt Chart into Beamer

Tags: beamer, gantt

Could you please help me fit my gantt chart into the beamer?

This is my code:

```
\begin{ganttchart}[
   y unit title=0.4cm,
    y unit chart=0.5cm,
    vgrid,
    time slot format=isodate-yearmonth,
    compress calendar,
    title/.append style={draw=none, fill=barblue},
    title label font=\sffamily\bfseries\color{white},
    title label node/.append style={below=-1.6ex},
    title left shift=.05,
    title right shift=-.05,
    title height=1,
    bar/.append style={draw=none, fill=groupblue},
    bar height=.6,
    bar label font=\normalsize\color{black!50},
    group right shift=0,
    group top shift=.6,
    group height=.3,
    group peaks height=.2,
    bar incomplete/.append style={fill=green}
   ]{2018-09}{2021-05}
   \gantttitlecalendar{year}\\
   \ganttbar[
    progress=100,
    bar progress label font=\small\color{barblue},
    bar progress label node/.append style={right=4pt},
    bar label font=\normalsize\color{barblue},
    name=pp
   ]{First Chapter}{2018-09}{2019-03} \\
\ganttset{progress label text={}, link/.style={black, -to}}
\ganttgroup{Second Chapter}{2019-01}{2020-09} \\
\ganttbar[progress=5, name=T1A]{Literature Review and Data Collection}{2019-01}{2019-09} \\
\ganttlinkedbar[progress=0]{Empirical Analysis and Writing}{2019-09}{2020-05} \\
\ganttlinkedbar[progress=0]{Seminars and Conferences}{2020-05}{2020-09} \\

\ganttgroup{Objective 2}{2020-09}{2021-06} \\
\ganttbar[progress=0, name=T2A]{Literature Review and Data Collection}{2020-09}{2021-01} \\
\ganttlinkedbar[progress=0]{Empirical Analysis and Writing}{2021-01}{2021-03} \\
\ganttlinkedbar[progress=0]{Seminars and Conferences}{2021-03}{2021-06} \\


  \ganttset{link/.style={green}}
  \ganttlink[link mid=.4]{pp}{T1A}
  \ganttlink[link mid=.159]{pp}{T2A}
\end{ganttchart}
```

thank you.

Comment: You could reduce the value of `x unit`, to something like `0.0075cm`. However, you will most likely also have to shorten the text in the left in order to fit the whole chart onto a beaer slide.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
x unit = 1mm,    
y unit title = 1mm,
y unit chart = 2mm,
bar label font = \tiny,
group label font = \tiny,
milestone label font = \tiny,
```

Start with all font sizes as `\tiny` for example and with small `x unit` widths. And maybe start with a simple setup and define the overall size -- after that add details one after another.